# Passing a variable as a parameter to a block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am running a code block in objective c and passing a variable as a parameter to it, the value of the variable changes inside the block. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
__block int timestamp=0; 
[MyAPI queryName:timestamp withBlock:^(Data *data) {
  NSLog(@"%@", data);
  timestamp = data.timestamp;
}];
```

I am not able to achieve this using the above code. Not sure what's the right way to get this done, or if it's doable in some other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming queryName:withBlock: is a call to your server? If so timestamp outside of the block gets updated at a later point and all your code below sees a timestamp of 0.

The solution is to do the execution that's dependant on the timestamp within the block call.

Comment: I am specifically listening to an open socket on the server, trying to build an instant messenger application. I am using firebase api.
`[[[self.myRootRef queryOrderedByChild:@"timestamp"] queryStartingAtValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:ts]] observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) { ts = snapshot.timestamp; } '

I don't know if I can really do the execution inside the block..